# Wordpress & Google Analytics : Source of visits

Tags: wordpress, facebook, google-analytics

Can we know the source of visits with details ?
The visits of a post in my blog has increased for 2 days. I know it's thanks facebook, but which page on Facebook ? Can we know that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean facebook ads or facebook organic traffic?

Comment: Facebook organic traffic

Comment: Facebook doesn't currently supply analytics on organic visits to your site. You can use UTM parameters to tag your URL's when sharing on facebook which shows the page the click comes from in Google analytics.

Example
1. http://youdomain.com/your-content?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=name-of-facebook-page

Then in Google Analytics this will show up under Acquisition > All Channels > Social > Facebook, and add a secondary dimension called Campaign.

Link to URL builder - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en